# Find special part in string php

Tags: php, string

We have a string like

```
<?php $str='this is a name or <span class="cut_string">40</span>' ?>
```

How can find the value of span (40). All string is dynamite and span value has been changeable span class is fix.

Comment: You can use PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse and extract the string.

Comment: yes use only php

Comment: DOMDocument _is_ PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Please help me ......

Comment: I've posted a link to the manual about how to solve it. Now it's up to you to read and learn how to use DOMDocument and make some attempt. SO isn't a free coding service where you just give us a task and we solve it for you. If you run into some _specific_ issue with your _existing_ code (after you've made some proper attempts), come back and show us what you've tried and we'll be glad to help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$result = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)